# Event triggered once the html binding is complete in Angular 2/4/5

Tags: html, angular

I have a parent component which has 2 child components like this

The data for the child components is coming in parent component from service and passed to the child components using input properties. As the data is very large and we have lot of custom components like ( Dropdowns and Tables). It takes time to bind the data to html elements as we have 47 droddowns in one child. 
I want to know an event which is fired when the html binding is complete i.e. the data in ts is binded to html and html is rendered properly?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have tried all the lifecycle hooks provided by angular but they are getting called before the html binding and rendering is completed.

Comment: Can you tell me what are the angular lifecycle hooks you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

"ngAfterViewInit() {}" is your choice. The HTML is rendered and the changeDetection with digest cycle has completed. Dont forget to implement "AfterViewInit" interface in your component.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply but the after view init is getting called even before the service is pulling the data. I would need something which is getting called and the data from service is binded with html.

Comment: The data of your service will come async. There is no event from angular for this. You have to fire an custom event in your then() or subscribe() to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

your custom directives will solve this problem. see the link

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sort-of-directives-in-angular-6-and-how-to-use-them/